# Can the surface of a 3-dimension cube be diffeomorphic to a 3-dimension sphere?

Tags: smooth-manifolds

We all know the surface of a cube homeomorphic to a sphere $S^3$ by retraction, but I'm confused that whether the surface of a cube can be diffeomorphic to $S^3$.

Comment: Do you mean the surface of the unit hypercube in $\Bbb R^4$, with the differential structure inherited from $\Bbb R^4$? I don't really know what happens at the edges and vertices there, but it looks messy.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "3-dimensional cube" and by "3-dimensional sphere"? I would think that the former is the three-fold product of the unit interval, and the latter is the unit sphere in $\Bbb R^4$. But those two spaces are not homeomorphic (e.g. their homology distinguishes them).

Comment: I think you mean a $3$ dimensional ball, which is a solid object like the earth.  We use sphere to represent the surface of a ball.

Comment: In addition, in order to ask if two things are diffeomorphic, both things must be smooth manifolds.  So, you must first choose some kind of atlas on the cube.

Comment: So the question is, if there exist a kind of atlas on cube, such that the cube with the atlas can be a smooth manifolds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me answer this in lower dimensions:

First, consider the bi-unit square $S$ (the boundary of $[-1, 1] \times [-1, 1]$ in $\Bbb R^2$) and the unit circle $C$ in $\Bbb R^2$.

There's a nice map ("radial projection") from the first to the second defined as follows:

$$
f(x, y) = \begin{cases}
(\frac{x}{\sqrt{y^2+1}}, \frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2 + 1}})& x = \pm 1 \\
(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}, \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}})& y = \pm 1 \\
\end{cases}
$$
which cane be written, more generally, as $f(x, y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} (x, y)$, but I wanted to emphasize that it's defined on the square, and that at the four corners, the expressions involved shift from a dependence on $x$ to a dependence on $y$ or vice versa.

The inverse of $f$ is 
$$
g(x, y) = \begin{cases}
(\frac{x}{|x|}, \frac{y}{|x|}) & |x| \ge |y|\\
(\frac{x}{|y|}, \frac{y}{|y|}) & |x| \le |y|
\end{cases}
$$

Now one smoothness structure on $S$ can be described as follows: we say that a function 
$$
u: S \to \Bbb R
$$ is smooth if and only iff
$$
u \circ g : C \to \Bbb R
$$
is smooth.

With this definition, the square $S$ is a smooth manifold, and it's diffeomorphic to the circle $C$, with $g$ being the diffeomorphism.

There's a small caveat here, though: the inclusion map
$$
i : S \to \Bbb R^2: (x, y) \mapsto (x, y)
$$
that embeds the square in the plane is *not* a smooth embedding.

What about higher dimensions? Well, an exact analog to $f$ can be written using more variables (and the "general" formula that I gave after the "cases" formula); the analog of $g$ involves 3 cases for a cube in 3-space (look at $|x|, |y|, |z|$: each case handles the situations where one of these is the largest).

When we get to 4-space, it's the same deal, but with another variable, and the formula for $g$ has four cases.

But everything else I said (including the fact that with the resulting smoothness structure, the standard embedding of the square/cube/hypercube is not a smooth embedding) remains true.

Comment: what's $s$ in $s\circ g$?

Comment: Fixed. It's "u" -- just a typo. Sorry about that.

Comment: I think I have got your point, thanks a lot.